Why did Drax ask this question?
Guardians of the Galaxy are in a decompression chamber at Orgocorp. Mantis notices their
spacesuits floating in space and exclaims. Gamora explains that the suits were thrown into
a contamination bin, which automatically expels its contents into space once the door is shut.
Mantis remarks that knowing this information earlier would have been helpful:

Nebula: Damn it, Mantis, why don't you ever think?
Drax: Are we pretending to be angry again? Mantis, you asshole!

Why did Drax ask this question?

Because he thought they were pretending to be angry.

Drax is not good at social situations. Previously, the group had bluffed their way past the guards by acting belligerent, forcing the guards on the defensive. Now, Nebula is suddenly angry, and Drax is asking whether they're back to play-acting, and proceeds to run with it, acting angry at Mantis.
An alternate explanation of the situation is that Drax is not genuinely confused, and plays up his social ignorance by exaggerating things for humor, whether to amuse himself or to break the tension of the room, but honestly, I think that he did misread the social cues.
